# Why z-index on element with position absolute not overlap its siblings inside a parent with position relative/absolute, but does when parent is fixed?

Tags: css

```css
.header {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%; 
}

.header p {
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px darkgray;
}

.header p:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 
    <p><a href="#">Something</a></p>
    <p>something two</p>
</div>
```

I have a parent with `position fixed`, and two child-elements. One is `position absolute`, and made to take the entire width thus covering its sibling. When I use `z-index -1`, the element goes beneath the sibling, not not beneath the parent.

However, if I make the parent `position relative` or `absolute`, instead of `fixed`, now the child-element with `z-index -1` goes beneath the parent as well.

```css
.header {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%; 
}

.header p {
    padding: 15px 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px darkgray;
}

.header p:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> 
    <p><a href="#">Something</a></p>
    <p>Something two</p>
</div>
```

I know this has something to do with the fact that, `fixed` is relative to the viewport, because same thing happens with `sticky` as well, but I would appreciate if someone explains what exactly is happening.

Comment: position fixed create a stacking context but not position:relative (unless you set z-index to it)

Comment: By "stacking context" you mean the child-elements have stacking order?

Comment: read the duplicate fully and you will understand